# android.os.MessageQueue.hasMessages(MessageQueue.java:~361) when calling service from onServiceConnected

Tags: java, android

Why do I get the error `android.os.MessageQueue.hasMessages(MessageQueue.java:~361)` when I send a message to the service from the onServiceConnected function in my ServiceConnection() object? The result I expect is to see a log printed with the string, "MyActivity.log: responseString: response" but instead something is hanging somewhere. To get a dump of what went wrong I caused an ANR by tapping the screen and waiting 5 seconds. This is the exception seen in the logs but the real problem is somewhere in my code, I'm causing something to hang. Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

My activity and service are pretty generic. The relevant parts are pasted below.

### MyActivity.java

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        sendToServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
        registerClient();
        sendMessageToService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        deregisterClient();
    }
};

private void registerClient() {
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MessageType.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT);
    msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
    try {
        sendToServiceMessenger.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Handles messages coming from the Service
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case MessageType.MSG_RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE:
                String responseString = (String) msg.obj;
                Log.v(TAG, "responseString: " + responseString);
            break;
        }
    }
};
private final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(mHandler);

private void sendMessageToService() {
    if (null == sendToServiceMessenger) {
        return;
    }

    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MessageType.MSG_SEND_TO_SERVICE);
    msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
    try {
        sendToServiceMessenger.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### MyService.java

```
public Handler receiveHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MessageType.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT:
                mClients.add(msg.replyTo);
                break;
            case MessageType.MSG_SEND_TO_SERVICE:
                String responseString = "response";
                sendString(MessageType.MSG_RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE, responseString);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void sendString (int messageType, String stringToSend) {
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, messageType);
    msg.obj = stringToSend;
    for (int i = mClients.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        try {
            mClients.get(i).send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            mClients.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging isn't going anywhere since the error message I receive is:

### Log

```
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: ANR in com.mypackage.mysubpackage (com.mypackage.mysubpackage/MyActivity)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: Load: 7.63 / 7.41 / 7.27
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 5183ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   98% 7458/com.mypackage.mysubpackage: 98% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   1.5% 911/system_server: 1.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 150 minor
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.7% 364/zygote: 0.5% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 292 minor
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.7% 412/mm-pp-daemon: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.7% 2127/adbd: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.3% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.3% 366/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.3% 1492/mpdecision: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.3% 2499/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.3% 6722/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0% 126/irq/342-atmel_m: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 363/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0% 484/lowi-server: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 517/sensors.qcom: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0% 6843/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 6904/kworker/u:14: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 7434/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 7502/kworker/1:1: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:  +0% 7508/com.mypackage.msapu: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:  +0% 7523/com.mypackage.msapm: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: 50% TOTAL: 48% user + 1.2% kernel + 0% iowait
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 1004ms to 1519ms later:
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   100% 7458/com.mypackage.mysubpackage: 100% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:     100% 7458/mypackage: 100% user + 0% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:   3.8% 911/system_server: 0% user + 3.8% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager:     1.9% 992/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911   992 E ActivityManager: 52% TOTAL: 50% user + 1.9% kernel
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager: Error reading /data/anr/traces.txt
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/anr/traces.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:146)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$12.run(ActivityManagerService.java:8576)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
01-04 03:09:44.555   911  7560 E ActivityManager:   ... 3 more
01-04 03:09:44.665   361   361 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-04 03:09:44.665   361   361 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'qcom/msm8974/msm8974:4.2.2/JDQ39/eng.lnxbuild.20130909.193415:userdebug/test-keys'
01-04 03:09:44.665   361   361 I DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-04 03:09:44.665   361   361 I DEBUG   : pid: 7458, tid: 7458, name: mysubpackage  >>> com.mypackage.mysubpackage <<<
01-04 03:09:44.665   361   361 I DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     r0 42846260  r1 42846260  r2 014294a0  r3 00000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     r4 014294a1  r5 41607d5c  r6 40bfd0d0  r7 00000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     r8 00000001  r9 00000004  sl 00000000  fp 0000048f
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     ip 00000000  sp beea86a8  lr 00000000  pc 5c9433f2  cpsr 80000030
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d2  000003e800000000  d3  0000000000000004
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d4  0079007400690076  d5  0065007200680054
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d6  006d002e00640061  d7  0028006e00690061
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d8  41a0000000000000  d9  442f0000442e8000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d10 00000000442f0000  d11 0000000000000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d16 00000001001e0003  d17 0000000100160101
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d18 0074007300790073  d19 004e002e006d0065
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d20 0076006900740061  d21 0061007400530065
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d22 006d002e00740072  d23 0028006e00690061
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d24 0028002700260024  d25 002a0028002a0029
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d28 001e001d001c001b  d29 0020001f001e001c
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     d30 002a002a002a002a  d31 0000000000000000
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     scr 6800009e
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     #00  pc 0001f3f2  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   : stack:
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8668  00000004  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea866c  41607d5c  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8670  0000048f  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8674  40883f14  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckBefore+556)
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8678  40bfd0d0  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea867c  40bfd0d0  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8680  00004000  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8684  00000001  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8688  5897de8a  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea868c  5897de88  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8690  41607d5c  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8694  40bfd0d0  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea8698  00001207  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea869c  40876b80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86a0  df0027ad  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86a4  00000000  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :     #00  beea86a8  00000000  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86ac  40bfd0d0  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86b0  40911c50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86b4  5767eba0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86b8  fffffe2c  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86bc  beea86dc  [stack]
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86c0  beea8780  [stack]
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86c4  00000000  
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86c8  4232367c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86cc  40884164  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+188)
01-04 03:09:44.755   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86d0  beea8700  [stack]
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86d4  4089df2b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHashTableLookup(HashTable*, unsigned int, void*, int (*)(void const*, void const*), bool)+50)
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86d8  00000000  
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86dc  58b17fb8  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86e0  41607ec4  
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   :          beea86e4  575ea390  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.765   361   361 I DEBUG   : memory near r0:
...
01-04 03:09:44.785   361   361 I DEBUG   : memory near r6:
...
01-04 03:09:44.785   361   361 I DEBUG   : memory near sp:
...
01-04 03:09:44.785   361   361 I DEBUG   : code around pc:
...
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : code around lr:
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :     000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Can't dump ETB. /dev/coresight-etb doesn't exist 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Crash in thread 1 at trace address 5c9433ac trace size 164
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Trace content dump:
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : dump memory region: 5c9433ac --> 5c943450
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c9433ac  f8d56869 696b8010 6a2f69ec 0001ea4f 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c9433bc  0100ea4f 69c9b1f1 60692900 801ff000 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c9433cc  f04fb311 6a4b38ff 42bb6a0a 800df2c0 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c9433dc  8009f300 0804ebb2 8007f000 f04fbf8c 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c9433ec  f04f38ff f1c80801 f1b80800 f77f0f00 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c9433fc  e00eafdd f8c560a8 616b8010 60a8e00f 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c94340c  8010f8c5 e011616b f8c560a8 616b8010 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c94341c  60a8e008 8010f8c5 e007616b f8dfde00 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c94342c  e001004c 0040f8df 47886ef1 4300e000 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c94343c  47806e70 5897de90 4300e000 47806e70 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5c94344c  5897de4c 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Crash in Landroid/os/MessageQueue;enqueueSyncBarrier(IJ)
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] First 4 trace runs (if any):
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :   Trace 0 start offset: 0x1e len: 3
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   :   Trace 1 start offset: 0x16 len: 1
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Dumping method DEX
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : dump memory region: 5897de4c --> 5897deb0
01-04 03:09:44.795   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897de4c  63f2061d 04d80014 64f50103 00710014 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897de5c  0000721e 03f5000c 0212002c 001061f4 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897de6c  00000416 04070431 000e0438 000c0138 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897de7c  002014f3 07040431 0006043c 11f41207 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897de8c  f528001c 00080238 001c01f7 001c20f7 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897de9c  030f061e 001c01f7 001060f7 040dfa28 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 5897deac  0427061e 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Stack walk: 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 0] 0x41607d5c Landroid/os/MessageQueue;enqueueSyncBarrier(IJ)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 1] 0x41607d94 Landroid/os/Looper;postSyncBarrier(I)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 2] 0x41607db8 Landroid/view/ViewRootImpl;scheduleTraversals(V)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 3] 0x41607de0 Landroid/view/ViewRootImpl;handleAppVisibility(VZ)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 4] 0x41607e00 Landroid/view/ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler;handleMessage(VL)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 5] 0x41607e64 Landroid/os/Handler;dispatchMessage(VL)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 6] 0x41607e84 Landroid/os/Looper;loop(V)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [ 7] 0x41607ec4 Landroid/app/ActivityThread;main(VL)
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Dumping dalvik stack errno: Success
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : 
01-04 03:09:44.805   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Dumping 128340 bytes from codeCache at 0x5c924000 into /data/user/log_7458.bin
01-04 03:09:45.075   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Dumping codeCache symbols into /data/user/log_7458.sym
01-04 03:09:45.225   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Dumping codecache to file errno: Success
01-04 03:09:45.225   361   361 I DEBUG   : [Dalvik] Dumping codecache errno: Success
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 W dalvikvm: threadid=3: spin on suspend #2 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm: "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42321e78 self=0x5ae00590
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   | sysTid=7463 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1096951768
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 1487602 5591875 42 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm: 
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE JIT
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42097b38 self=0x40bfd0d0
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   | sysTid=7458 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074855132
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 9065612838 633459565 4287 ) utm=889 stm=17 core=1
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:~239)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.os.Looper.postSyncBarrier(Looper.java:227)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scheduleTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:973)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleAppVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:802)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2867)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5074)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 03:09:45.325  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 03:09:45.325   911   966 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-04 03:09:45.335  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-04 03:09:45.335  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-04 03:09:45.335  7458  7463 I dalvikvm:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if your taking too much time to respond to a key dispatching event.
A Timer is set on a key event that causes the exception you see on timeout (that is if a key dispatching takes too long to return)

You should consider doing less work on the main Thread.

Use `new Thread(myRunnable).start()` to execute non UiThread code outside of the Main Thread

Comment: In particular, avoid doing network operations (looking your code it seems there might be some). A special strict mode even exists in Android that will throw if networking is being done on the main Thread.

Comment: They only reason I'm taking too long to respond to a key dispatch event is because of the ANR caused by a bug in my code that I've posted. It should never take >5 seconds (how long it takes to trigger and ANR) to send a message to the service and receive a message back from the service. And no, no networking is happening- just the code posted.

Comment: And the real exception that caused this is then `Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)`?

Comment: I caused the exception to get a dump to be able to better debug what's causing the hang up. I've edited my post to include this, "To get a dump of what went wrong I caused an ANR by tapping the screen and waiting 5 seconds. This is the exception seen in the logs but the real problem is somewhere in my code, I'm causing something to hang."

Comment: Seems to me like a threading issue. I'd guess you've got the Ui thread being blocked at some point. But I don't know if its in the code you posted or somewhere else. I'll try investigate the javadoc to find if some method should be executed in a particular thread, but i suggest you run your program in debug mode and pause it when you think your error his happening, then try to see if some thread is waiting on a lock, or something else it shouldn't.
If you don't provoke the ANR as you explained, your program just doesn't throw anything ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works :

```
public class ServiceTestActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT         = 0x00000001;
    public static final int MSG_SEND_TO_SERVICE         = 0x00000002;
    public static final int MSG_RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE   = 0x00000003;

    private static final String TAG = ServiceTestActivity.class.getName();

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            sendToServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
            registerClient();
            sendMessageToService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            //deregisterClient();
        }
    };

    // Handles messages coming from the Service
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
                case MSG_RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE:
                    String responseString = (String) msg.obj;
                    Log.v(TAG, "responseString: " + responseString);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    private Messenger sendToServiceMessenger;
    private final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(mHandler);

    private void registerClient() {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT);
        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
        try {
            sendToServiceMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessageToService() {
        if (null == sendToServiceMessenger) {
            return;
        }

        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_SEND_TO_SERVICE);
        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
        try {
            sendToServiceMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bindService(new Intent(this, ServiceTest.class).putExtra("messenger", mMessenger), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
}
```

And the Service :

```
public class ServiceTest extends Service {

    /* INSTANCE FIELDS */
        final List<Messenger> mClients = new LinkedList<Messenger>();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new Messenger(receiveHandler).getBinder();
    }

    public Handler receiveHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case ServiceTestActivity.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT:
                    mClients.add(msg.replyTo);
                    break;
                case ServiceTestActivity.MSG_SEND_TO_SERVICE:
                    String responseString = "response";
                    sendString(ServiceTestActivity.MSG_RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE, responseString);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private void sendString (int messageType, String stringToSend) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, messageType);
        msg.obj = stringToSend;
        for (int i = mClients.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            try {
                mClients.get(i).send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                mClients.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```